# Reading special characters from URL query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, request.querystring

I have a situation where the user is able to enter any characters they want in a URL query string.

Example:

http://localhost/default.aspx?ID=a‡jljglkjg

How can I accept special characters such as ‡, ˆ, and † in asp.net from a URL query string? I am finding that when I attempt to retrieve these URL query string these special characters gets replaced with a “?”.

Note: The user inputs these query string into the URL.

Comment: why not make UrlEncode ? is this not permitted ? And second, how you try to retrieve this characters - with what function ?

Comment: I am using Request.QueryString to retrieve these characters.

Answer (score 1):

This URL is **wrong** according to [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt).

- If they are using browser, it would normally do the **ecndoing** required.
- If it is done by JavaScript, use `encodeURIcomponent`
- If it is a C# app, using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx)

Comment: How is it possible that classic ASP can process this request correctly but not asp.net?

Comment: Also caret(^) is a valid request but that also gets replaced with a question mark. Why is that?

Comment: ASP can since it probably cleans it up before processing. With `^` I think gets confused.

Comment: In the case of asp.net then is it possible to clean it up before processing as well or solve this problem somehow?

Comment: It could be. Have a look at URL-Rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

> URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the [ASCII character-set](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp).

Those characters will always be excluded, you need to find another way to do it.

Comment: I have a legacy application using classic ASP which is able to correctly take in this query string and display it back out again.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp for more information about valid URLs and encoding special characters.